# Same TypeScript Custom Generic type works different between two cases

Tags: typescript

I have a custom TypeScript Generic type but this one works differently between the two cases.

I use it for more than 20 cases and all work but it does not work in only one condition.

```
type Previous = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...0[]];
export type DotPrefix<T extends string> = T extends "" ? "" : `.${T}`;

type PathsConditional<T, C, D extends number = 4> = [D] extends [never]
  ? never
  : (
      T extends C
        ? ""
        : T extends Array<infer E>
        ? E extends C
          ? `${number}`
          : `${number}.${PathsConditional<E, C, Previous[D]>}`
        : T extends object
        ? {
            [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]: `${K}${DotPrefix<
              PathsConditional<T[K], C, Previous[D]>
            >}`;
          }[Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]
        : never
    ) extends infer D
  ? Extract<D, string>
  : never;

type AllowedNames<Base extends object, _Condition> = PathsConditional<
  Base,
  _Condition
>;

export interface PrivateStaff {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  username: string;
  password?: string;
  roleId: number;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  allowedOwners?: Owner[];
  allowedOwnerIds?: string[];
}

export interface Owner {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  allowedModels?: Model[];
  allowedModelIds?: string[];
  allowedYears?: number[];
  allowedMaxOdometer?: number;
  createdAt?: string;
  updatedAt?: string;
}

export interface Model {
  id?: number;
  ownerId?: string;
  verifiedAt?: string;
  makeId?: number;
  collectionId?: number;
  vehicleBodyTypeId?: number;
  engine?: string;
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
  descriptionLong?: string;
  tags?: string;
  seatQty?: number;
  tankSize?: number;
  comingSoon?: boolean;
  owner?: Owner;
  years?: number[];
  colors?: string[];
}

const dataKey1: AllowedNames<PrivateStaff, Owner | Owner[]> = "allowedOwners";

const dataKey2: AllowedNames<Owner, Model | Model[]> = "allowedModels";
```

I am adding TypeScript Playground link below. I need help with this.

[TypesScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAbgSwPYFcDOUC8UDaAdkhHADRQAMFAjBQEwUDMFALBQKwUB0vl+AXQEBuAFAQAHmFRxgUUJCgARVMHgQAZsgkAeACpRJwCIQAm2TMDjJCAcwB8uKAaMnzUAEQeoAfk-eALigAA24AEgBvPQBfYLFRBWgYAENgAAtMAGFUM2RgNEJkgBt9CkyKJUMJYzNsQnQAWwAjUidWRzx8JQEqmvciEjgBUShfKGJEUhGoIIAKadHRl2q3bEyFxdG-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-87KgYySwATQgZIOKDHC4E87ynOSCRmNMVBKzXTjfjBPCCOMIjgHc5DyMo6i0u0qSZMXeSVyUzdoGcoooA0i94uCwCi3YzD0rIqBJmsLQS2IxrDKgBpkkFBqgr+OA8OlIoqR7frsMGwDJjSZAuQgGtzJAPRwAwrTJsS6YTFsGw9Ny0ZdM6wDeUwfDkDAHsjumE6zougoABkclsK7RiPWwrPAgzAIbVIAEVQGqqbpiPQh+X3ZAAC89o23DpkpGK033VAck4v00OSQharUuBOKEobphAfzAphkKRDh6UZA+8TbEk6TRHhwhLCgKijyZIUaCCPNGJLH9q3gZBd2MQ9jw0Cg8agAAfVSeJxJwPDCvHMA8eIGaZlnkjZkB6E5hymN5nQ8YoMrJagMrBD7eXdZLMqleEIA)

Comment: the provided code has a syntax problem and has nothing to do with the question

Comment: I corrected the link. @tachibana-shin

Comment: I see `T extends C ? "" : ...` and `PrivateStaff is assignable to Owner` but then `Owner is not assignable to Model (types of the property 'id' are not compatible)`

Comment: You are choosing to terminate when `T extends C`, but `PrivateStaff extends Owner` so of course you're not getting it to keep recursing.  If you want to recurse even when you hit `C`, then you'll get more paths, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkDyjw).  Not sure how you want to approach that, but this is presumably the information you're asking for. I'd be happy to write up an answer assuming that fully addresses your question as asked; if not, then what specifically am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved. The problem is that PrivateStaff is assignable to Owner because all properties of the Owner are optional. If I make the `id` and `name` properties of the Owner required then the problem is solved.

Comment: So you're just passing in different inputs?  I thought you wanted someone to fix the `PathsConditional<T>` type so it worked for your existing inputs.  It looks like you're *avoiding* the problem, not *solving* it.